# How to receive input and reverse string in Microsoft Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, input, output, reverse

I am creating a simple program in Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 for school and I need some help. 
**This is what I want to do:**

1. Receive input from user via keyboard
2. Create a button that user presses to reverse string
3. Print their inputted text in reverse

This is what the GUI looks like so far:

[image: my gui, but where do I access the code?]

I know that in Python you would do something like:

```
user_input = input("Enter your string")
user_input = user_input[::-1]
print(user_input)
```

But I am completely lost in MVS. How do I even access the code for my text boxes, and button? I am also unsure what language this program uses, is it C#?

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Double click your button for reversing and that will create the `Click` event and take you to the code view.

Comment: Alternatively, (single) click on the button, click on the lightning bolt on the `Properties` pane.  This will show you all the events you can subscribe to.  Double click the right hand side of the event item and it will create the event for you.

Comment: Yes, that is C# (`.cs` is used by C#)

Answer (score 0):

You can create an extension method to reverse the string, something like:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string Reverse(this string toReverse)
    {
        var stringArray = toReverse.ToCharArray();
        Array.Reverse(stringArray);
        return new string(stringArray);
    }
}
```

On your form class, youll have to bind to the click event:

```
btnReverser.Click += OnBtnClick;

private void OnBtnClick(object sender, ButtonEventArgs e)
{
    var reverse = textbox1.Text.Reverse();
    label1.Text = reverse;
}
```

Comment: hmmmm - he is a student. Give him some hints not write the whole thing for him...

Answer (score 0):

An easier way would be: after you double click on the button :

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string str;
            str = textBox1.Text;
            char[] arr = str.ToCharArray();
            Array.Reverse(arr);
            string str2 = new string(arr);
            textBox2.Text = str2;
        }
```

Comment: An easier way than what? And why did you make your text giant?